# javascript squares dont move properly

Tags: javascript

i have two red squares that are supposed to move to the blue square but only one of the red squares will move. the other red square just sits there doing nothing and i have no idea why. i tried putting the code that makes the square almost everywhere but it still wont work. i plan to add possibly hundreds of squares for both teams if the framerate would allow it, so it is important that i find a way to loop creating squares, or my entire game would be kinda boring. i also plan to make a way to edit the values of the squares while the game is running. i dont know if that information is relevent to my problem but im going to include it anyway in the situation that it is helpful with fixing my problem.

```
var color = 1;
//var redTeamSpeedX = redTeam[index].speedX;
var speed = 1;
var blueTeam = [];
var redTeam = [];
var blueBase;
var redBase;
var blueTeamHealth = 100;
var blueTeamAttack = 10;
var blueTeamDefence = 1;
var redTeamHealth = 50;
var redTeamAttack = 20;
var redTeamDefence = 1;
var blueAttackP = "blue Team Attack:" + blueTeamAttack;
var blueHealthP = "blue Team HP:" + blueTeamHealth;
var blueDefenceP= "blue Team Defence:"+ blueTeamDefence;
var redAttackP = "red Team Attack:" + redTeamAttack;
var redHealthP = "red Team HP:" + redTeamHealth;
var redDefenceP = "red Team Defence:" + redTeamDefence;
function startGame() {
    blueTeam.push(new component(15, 15, "blue", 20, 20));
  
  //redTeam.push(new component(15, 15, "red", 450, 240));
  
    
  blueBase = new component(40, 40, "teal", 10, 10);
  redBase = new component(40, 40, "darkred", 430, 220);
myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;        
    }    
    
}
redTeam.push(new component(15,15,"red",450,200));
redTeam.push(new component(15,15,"red",450,200));
function updateGameArea() {
myGameArea.clear();
 blueTeam.forEach(blueTeamUpdate);
  redTeam.forEach(redTeamUpdate);

   document.getElementById("blueHP").innerHTML = "blue team health" + blueTeamHealth;
  document.getElementById("blueAttack").innerHTML = "blue team attack" + blueTeamAttack;
  document.getElementById("blueDefence").innerHTML = "blue team defence" + blueTeamDefence;
    //blueBase.update();
   // redBase.update();
    }
  function blueTeamUpdate(item,index) {
    blueTeam[index].update();
    blueTeam[index].newPos();
    
    
    if(blueTeam[index].x > redTeam[index].x) {
    //blueTeam[index].speedX = -1;
      if(blueTeam[index].speedX > speed) {
    blueTeam[index].speedY += 1;
  } else if(blueTeam[index].speedX < speed) {
    blueTeam[index].speedY += -1;
  }
  }
  if(blueTeam[index].x < redTeam[index].x) {
   // blueTeam[index].speedX = 1;
    if(blueTeam[index].speedX > speed) {
    blueTeam[index].speedX += -1;
  } else if(blueTeam[index].speedX < speed) {
    blueTeam[index].speedX += 1;
  }
  }
  if(blueTeam[index].y < redTeam[index].y) {
  if(blueTeam[index].speedY < speed) {
    blueTeam[index].speedY += 1;
  } else if(blueTeam[index].speedY > speed) {
    blueTeam[index].speedY += -1;
  }
  }
  if(blueTeam[index].y > redTeam[index].y) {
    if(blueTeam[index].speedY > negspeed) {
    blueTeam[index].speedY += -1;
    } else if(blueTeam[index].speedY < negspeed) {
      blueTeam[index].speedY += 1;
    }
  }

    if(blueTeam[index].x < (redTeam[index].x + redTeam[index].x) && (blueTeam[index].x + blueTeam[index].width) > redTeam[index].x) {
      redTeam[index].speedX = 0 ;//- redTeam[index].speedX * 5;
      blueTeam[index].speedX = 0 - blueTeam[index].speedX * 5;
      if (redTeamHealth > 0) {
      redTeamHealth -= (blueTeamAttack/redTeamDefence);
      } else {
       // redTeam[index].speedX = 0;
       // redTeam[index].speedY = 0;
      }
      if (blueTeamHealth > 0) {
      blueTeamHealth -= (redTeamAttack/blueTeamDefence);
    } else {
        blueTeam[index].speedX = 0;
        blueTeam[index].speedY = 0;
       
    
        
    }
    }
  }
function redTeamUpdate(item, index, arr) {
  redTeam[index].update();
  redTeam[index].newPos();
  //redTeam[indedx].newPos();
  //redTeam[index].speedX = -1;

  if(redTeam[index].x < blueTeam[index].x) {
   // redTeam[index].speedX = 1;
    if(redTeam[index].speedX > speed) {
    redTeam[index].speedX += -1;
  } else if(redTeam[index].speedX < speed) {
    redTeam[index].speedX += 1;
  }
  }
if(redTeam[index].x > blueTeam[index].x) {
   // redTeam[index].speedX = 1;
    if(redTeam[index].speedX > negspeed) {
    redTeam[index].speedX += -1;
  } else if(redTeam[index].speedX < negspeed) {
    redTeam[index].speedX += 1;
  }
  }

  
  if(redTeam[index].y < blueTeam[index].y) {
  if(redTeam[index].speedY < speed) {
    redTeam[index].speedY += 1;
  } else if(redTeam[index].speedY > speed) {
    redTeam[index].speedY += -1;
  }
  }
  if(redTeam[index].y > blueTeam[index].y) {
    if(redTeam[index].speedY > negspeed) {
    redTeam[index].speedY += -1;
    } else if(redTeam[index].speedY < negspeed) {
      redTeam[index].speedY += 1;
    }
  }

  
  }

   //if(blueTeam[index].x < (redTeam[index].x + redTeam[index].x) && (blueTeam[index].x + blueTeam[index].width) > redTeam[index].x) {
    //  redTeam[index].speedX = 10;
   //}
```

i did use a bit of html

```
<html>
<head>
<p id="blueHP"></p>
  <p id="blueAttack"></p>
  <p id="blueDefence"></p>
  <p id="redHP"></p>
  <p id="redAttack"></p>
  <p id="redDefence"></p>
 
</head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba (0,0,0,0);
}
</style>
  
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body onload="startGame()">
  

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: There are a number of things that could be causing part of your problem, such as a variable `ctx` which is not defined (and is thus defaulting to a global variable, probably not intended). Another variable `negspeed` doesn't appear to ever be defined but you're using it in `if` statements. You also have a couple of `redTeam.push` statements outside of any function, which might be running out of order. As opposed to your `blueTeam.push` which happens in `startGame`.

Comment: I don't know if these are your only problem(s), or if it's causing the faulty behavior. There's so much code I don't have time to go through all of it (see [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))...but I ran your JS code through eslint and these problems showed up. A good linter and a dev environment with code formatting might be good tools for you to look into.

Comment: `negspeed` is defined i probibly just forgot to include it. `push.redTeam` is origanily from `startGame` but i also forgot to put that back too. i fixed `ctx`, but it never caused any problems. my code still doesent work, but i found that both squares move if i put the move command outside of the `if` commands. i dont think it should matter if they are inside or outside the `if` command but the ones inside the `if` command only moves one square. normally this would not be a problem, exept i need my squares to move to the blue square and i don't really know any other ways besides `if` commands.